# Regex match but exclude

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having some trouble with *regex* in **JavaScript**. I need to test whether a URL matches this simple pattern, invoking the `RegExp.prototype.test(value: string): boolean` method.

I want the result to be `true` for URLs like this:

```
/somePath
/anyPath
/doesNotMatterWhatIsHere
```

And I'd like it to return `false` for any path that is like this:

```
/
/somePath/someWhereElse
/anyPath/1
/doesNotMatterWhatIsHere/pickle/chips/are/awesome
```

The point being, if it is the root `/path` I want `true` and if it is anything other than this, I want `false`. Please help.

I have been using http://regexr.com/.

My Regex I have thus far, `\/.+[^\/]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure it begins with `/` and does not contain `/` anywhere else

```js
var test1 = "/somePath";
var test2 = "/anyPath";
var test3 = "/doesNotMatterWhatIsHere";

var empty = "/";

var fail1 = "/somePath/someWhereElse";
var fail2 = "/anyPath/1";
var fail3 = "/doesNotMatterWhatIsHere/pickle/chips/are/awesome";

regex = /^[/]([^/]+)$/;

console.log(regex.test(test1));
console.log(regex.test(fail1));
console.log(regex.test(empty));
```

Comment: I would also like to ensure the the path is not simply a forward slash, this regex doesn't correctly account for that. `var test1 = "/"; // I want this to be false`.

Comment: Just change `*` to `+`

Answer (score 1):

Something like `^[^/]*/[^/]*$` maybe ?

or, `/^[^\/]*\/[^\/]*$/` with delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, this regex would work: `/^\/[^\/]*$/`. It basically checks that the first character is a `/` and the rest of the characters are not `/`.

But I suspect you might also want to match `"/somePath/"` as it is common to treat trailing slash as a canonical URL.

If you want to do so, this regex will take the trailing slash into account:

```
/^\/[^\/]*\/?$/
```

It checks that the first character is a `/`, and the rest of the characters are not `/`, and an optional `/` at the end.

Comment: This expression incorrectly returns `true` for just a `/`. I want that to be `false`.

Comment: For future reference, please be clear in your question from the start to prevent miscommunication.

Comment: I was clear... but things change, I initially didn't consider the root only `/`. Thank you for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var pattern=/^\/[^\/]+$/;
console.info(pattern.test('/somePath'));
console.info(pattern.test('/doesNotMatterWhatIsHere'));
console.info(pattern.test('/somePath/someWhereElse'));
console.info(pattern.test('/doesNotMatterWhatIsHere/pickle/chips/are/awesome'));
```

try it